# Mocha Sinon testing ajax request (in Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, chai

How to test a Ajax request using mocha and sinon?

Here is the initialize function say in a class called testApp :

```
 testApp.prototype.initialize=function() {
  $.get(....);
}
```

in the tests if I say,

```
sinon.stub($,"get", function(d,e) {});
var test = new testApp();
```

this line throws the error $ is not defined.

I am using grunt to run the mochatests.

I tried using $ and jQuery. But I always get the variable as undefined.

Can someone help out on this?

Comment: The error you get definitely means that jQuery is not loaded!Once jQuery is loaded, you would be able to do so... but I would defintely use sinon.spy($,"get") and check if it's called or not, with or without the desired argument then restore the spy. if you want to test in standalone mode, I will then use a sinon.FakeXML/Server! what version of SinonJS do you use? http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.6/fake-xhr-and-server/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution tested in Node environment. So I use `jsdom` to provide a mocked window for `jQuery`. Otherwise, `$.ajax` and `$.get` methods will be `undefined`.

`index.js`:

```js
const $ = require("./jquery");

function TestApp() {}

TestApp.prototype.initialize = function() {
  $.get("https://github.com/mrdulin");
};

module.exports = TestApp;
```

`jquery.js`:

```js
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM();
const { document } = new JSDOM("").window;
global.document = document;

var $ = require("jquery")(window);

module.exports = $;
```

`index.spec.js`:

```js
const $ = require("./jquery");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const TestApp = require(".");

describe("TestApp", () => {
  it("should initialize", () => {
    const getStub = sinon.stub($, "get");
    const test = new TestApp();
    test.initialize();
    sinon.assert.calledWith(getStub, "https://github.com/mrdulin");
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
  TestApp
    ✓ should initialize


  1 passing (38ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 jquery.js     |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/37867917